# Live Server works but I get 404 error for localhost

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I have my server and client on different projects.

When I'm using Live Server on vsCode then everything works. But not if I try to go to localhost, then I get 404.

How come?

server.js

```
const logger = require('./logger');
const PORT = 3000;
const io = require('socket.io')(PORT);
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const socketListeners = require('./sockets/socketListeners');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', socket => socketListeners(socket, io, logger));
```

index.js (on client)

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', appendForm());
```

With debugger on client I get "io is not defined".
When I use "import io from "socket.io-client" on line 1 I get unexpected identifier.

EDIT

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Chat</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.5/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script src="name.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <script src="chat.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="container"></section>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
//const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
const socket = io(':3000');

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', appendForm());
```

name.js

```
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const nameContainer = document.createElement('section');
const title = document.createElement('h1');
const form = document.createElement('form');
const nameInput = document.createElement('input');
const submitName = document.createElement('button');

title.innerText = 'Enter Your Name';
submitName.innerText = 'Connect';

const getName = () => {
  form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const name = nameInput.value;
    socket.emit('new-user', name);
    nameInput.value = '';
    socket.off('invalid-name');
    socket.on('invalid-name', () => {
      feedbackBox(
        "Make sure you don't have space or other funky characters in your name \n \n Must be between 3-13 characters"
      );
    });
    socket.off('name-taken');
    socket.on('name-taken', () => {
      feedbackBox('Nickname already taken');
    });
    socket.off('user-accepted');
    socket.on('user-accepted', () => {
      title.classList.add('hide');
      nameContainer.classList.add('hide');
      addMessageForm();
    });
  });
};

const appendForm = () => {
  nameInput.classList.add('name_input');
  form.appendChild(nameInput);
  submitName.classList.add('submit_name');
  form.appendChild(submitName);
  nameContainer.appendChild(form);
  nameContainer.classList.add('name_container');
  nameContainer.classList.remove('hide');
  title.classList.remove('hide');
  title.classList.add('name_title');
  container.appendChild(title);
  container.appendChild(nameContainer);
  getName();
};
```

chat.js

```
//const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

const showFeedback = document.createElement('section');
const messageContainer = document.createElement('section');
const messageForm = document.createElement('form');
const messageInput = document.createElement('input');
const submitMessage = document.createElement('button');
const disconnectButton = document.createElement('button');

submitMessage.innerText = 'Send';
disconnectButton.innerText = 'X';

messageContainer.classList.add('message-container');
messageForm.classList.add('send-container');
messageInput.classList.add('message-input');
submitMessage.classList.add('send-button');
disconnectButton.classList.add('disconnect-button');

const addMessageForm = () => {
  showFeedback.classList.add('hide');
  messageContainer.classList.remove('hide');
  messageForm.classList.remove('hide');
  disconnectButton.classList.remove('hide');
  messageForm.appendChild(messageInput);
  messageForm.appendChild(submitMessage);
  container.appendChild(disconnectButton);
  container.appendChild(messageContainer);
  container.appendChild(messageForm);
  appendMessage('You joined');
};

socket.on('chat-message', data => {
  appendMessage(`${data.name}: ${data.message}`);
});

socket.on('user-connected', name => {
  appendMessage(`${name} connected`);
});

socket.on('user-disconnected', name => {
  appendMessage(`${name} left the chat`);
});

socket.on('user-inactivity-disconnected', name => {
  appendMessage(`${name} was disconnected due to inactivity`);
});

messageForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const message = messageInput.value;
  socket.emit('send-chat-message', message);
  if (message !== '') {
    appendMyMessage(`You: ${message}`);
  }
  messageInput.value = '';
});

function appendMessage(message) {
  const messageElement = document.createElement('section');
  messageElement.innerText = message;
  messageElement.classList.add('messages');
  messageContainer.append(messageElement);
}

function appendMyMessage(message) {
  const myMessageElement = document.createElement('section');
  myMessageElement.innerText = message;
  myMessageElement.classList.add('myMessage');
  messageContainer.append(myMessageElement);
}

const feedbackBox = message => {
  showFeedback.innerText = message;
  showFeedback.classList.add('feedback-I-disconnect');
  showFeedback.classList.remove('hide');
  container.appendChild(showFeedback);
};

disconnectButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('disconnect-button')) {
    socket.disconnect();
    messageContainer.classList.add('hide');
    messageForm.classList.add('hide');
    disconnectButton.classList.add('hide');
    appendForm();
    feedbackBox('You disconnected from the chat');
    socket.connect();
  }
});

socket.on('inactive', () => {
  socket.emit('disconnected');
  messageContainer.classList.add('hide');
  messageForm.classList.add('hide');
  disconnectButton.classList.add('hide');
  appendForm();
  feedbackBox('Disconnected by the server due to inactivity');
});
```

Comment: Bro have you got any solution ? i have same problem

Answer (score 2):

First, fix your link to the Socket.io library in index.html. try cdn, like this `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.5/socket.io.min.js"></script>`
I had a similar problem. Try this for connection to localhost:

```
const socket = io(':3000'); // pay attention on that it should be a string and starts with a colon symbol
```

EDIT

First you need to remove `defer` attribute from `<script defer src="...>` loading. This tells browser to keep loading the page while this defer script loading in background and run this script after it became loaded.

So, in your case, the script with Socket.io library will be run AFTER it required in the line `const socket = io('...`

Comment: I did, and it still doesn't work. When I debug I get "io is not defined"

Comment: Not sure I fully understood but I updated my edit version above. The html and index.js files, but still doesn't work with localhost. Now not even with live server

Comment: @tratatun thanks bro this helped me

Answer (score 1):

Try using `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.5/socket.io.min.js"></script>` in your client. I think it should work.

Comment: Still the same problem

Comment: Can you update some more code of client side just to understand it more ?